# Failed to load: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, payment-gateway, payumoney, payu

I was working on PayU Payment gateway integration in Spring MVC where i was supposed to use the jars of already implemented java classes. In order to do that i created a controller class where i call the required methods of the included jars. Now when i am making the ajax request it is showing me the following error:

> Failed to load
>
> http://localhost:8081/ABHI/payupg/payReqHDFC/600/SAU/Robert/robert@gmail.com/9876543210?{}:
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

My Ajax request is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/myFolder/Desktop/code_testing/jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
    var testData =  {}
    //var testData =    {"userName":"robert","password":"Test@12345"}
        var URL= "http://localhost:8081/ABHI/payupg/payReqHDFC/600/SAU/Robert/robert@gmail.com/9876543210";

            $.ajax({
                url : URL,
                async :false,
                type : 'GET',
                dataType : 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(testData),
                contentType : 'application/json',
                mimeType : 'application/json',
                crossDomain : true,
                success : function(data) {  
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
                alert(data);
                },
                error : function(data, status, er) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
                    console.log("Errors : ");  //+data.responseJSON.errorMessage
                }
            });
            }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="test()"> Click me </button>
</body>
</html>
```

My PayUController.java is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/payupg")
public class PayuController {

    @Autowired
    HdfcController hdfcController;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/payReqHDFC/{amount}/{productInfo}/{firstname}/{email}/{phone}" },
                    method = {org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET })
    public String paymentGateway(Model model, @PathVariable String amount, @PathVariable String productinfo,
            @PathVariable String firstname, @PathVariable String email, @PathVariable String phone) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("inside controller");
        String str=hdfcController.payReqHDFCGateway(model,null,amount,productinfo,firstname,email,phone,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        System.out.println("End of inside controller");

        // return "hdfcPayReq";
        // return PGConstants.HDFC_PAY_REQ_PAGE;
        return str;
    }
}
```

For more clarification i would like to say you can avoid the CROS-Origin issue.

In this Payment gateway almost 15 parameters are the there to be sent out of which 5-6 are mandatory. I am sending those only and rest i am setting null.